# validation in angular coming up on page

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I am using angularjs, were i have defined some routes and on the html page i have used some validations.
My html page looks like:

```
<form  ng-controller="validateCtrl"
       name="loginForm" novalidate>

    <p>UserName:<br>
        <input type="text" name="uName" ng-model="uName" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="loginForm.uName.$dirty && loginForm.uName.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="loginForm.uName.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
  </span>
    </p>

    <p>Password:<br>
        <input type="text" name="pwd" ng-model="pwd" required>
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="loginForm.pwd.$dirty && loginForm.pwd.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="loginForm.pwd.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
  </span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="popupuser()"
               ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid ">
    </p>

</form>
```

When i run the page in browser, all the errors/validations are showing up on page load itself.
I would like the validation error to only come up, when there is any error on particular control and wants the button to be disabled, until and unless the form is fully valid.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body  ng-app="test">
<div id="links">
    <a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
    <a ui-sref="register">Register</a>
</div>
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('test', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('register', {
                url: '/register',
                templateUrl: '../partials/register.html',
                controller: 'registration'
            });
        $stateProvider.state('login',{
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: '../partials/login.html',
            controller: 'login'
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your `$dirty` checks should be preventing this. Can you provide a JSFiddle example?

Comment: @AlexG: http://jsfiddle.net/jqya8zy3/

Comment: @kawade fiddle does not contain any javascript code

Comment: You're not using angular. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/jqya8zy3/1/

Comment: thanks @AlexG. please let me know where to add this js

Comment: @AlexG: please let me know where to update my code so to have this functionality working?

Answer (score 0):

your code should work as is. check out this [plunker..](http://plnkr.co/edit/zQeHUo8mjTTDTo8655ly?p=preview)

what you need is ng-app somewhere in your html

```
     <html ng-app="plunker">
     .
     .
     .
     </html>
```

Comment: i tried doing teh whole code in login.html, but have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885149/html-file-coming-up-with-2-controls

Comment: i have copied whole code from plunker and paste on y code, but stil showing the validation on page load

Comment: thats because you have seperate index.html & login.html. can you share both html code in your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61402/discussion-between-kawade-and-harishr).

Comment: please let me know how to and where to add that

Comment: please let me know where to add this in app.js?